# Perl cgi doesn't work with Opts::validate()

Tags: perl, cgi

The code below gives me

> End of script output before headers: secondcgi

But when i comment `Opts::validate();` line it works fine.
Can you help me?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI;
use VMware::VIRuntime;
my %opts;

Opts::add_options(%opts);
Opts::parse();
Opts::validate();


print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
print "<html>";
print "<head>";
print "<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>";
print "</head>";
print "<body>";
print "start";

Util::connect();
print "second start after connect";
&check_server;
print "<h2>Hello alsu</h2>";
print "$message";
print "</body>";
print "</html>";
```

if i move it after like this

```
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
print "<html>";
print "<head>";
print "<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>";
print "</head>";
print "<body>";
print "start <br>";
Opts::validate();
print "<h2>can't see this part</h2>";
print "$result";
print "</body>";
print "</html>";
```

i can't see nothing below this line

Answer (score 1):

That error specifically means that *something* in your script printed prior to the script headers:

```
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
```

Without a `Content-Type` the webserver generates that error, so that *probably* means your `Opts::validate();` is generating some sort of output or warning.

Try moving it to after the content type line, and see what it *actually* prints. (view source in your web page).